# Resampling images with Node.js

Tags: image, node.js, image-processing

I have searched the net pretty thoroughly and have yet to find anything.

Is there a way with Node.js to resample images, for example, make a 800x600 image a 400x300 image for better web performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed on your system and then you can use a Node module to interact with it: https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick

It worked for me fine on Ubuntu with Node 0.4.x, I haven't tested with the latest 0.6.x though.

Another alternative (which I haven't tested but I've heard great things about) is [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas).

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is *3 times faster* than ImageMagic.

You can try to compare Node.js modules for images manipulation - https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

Canvas usage examples: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas