# Use GD library in NodeJS to copy and resample image

Tags: image, node.js, gd

I try, unsuccessfully, to find an equivalent in NodeJS of PHP GD function `imagecopyresampled`.

This is not simply resize an image, but get a portion of an image and then put it into another image.

I find this libraries :

- gm
- canvas
- imagemagick
- easyimage
- node-gd

But they have no equivalent. It's the same thing with the function `imagecreatetruecolor` and they just simply resize/crop image without select part of image with offset and specified width/height selection.

Does anyone know the NodeJS equivalent ?

Comment: [You obviously didn't try very hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467658/resampling-images-with-node-js). More specifically, [this is what you want](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick#resizeoptions-callbackerr-stdout-stderr). Don't look for something expecting it to have the same name

Comment: This is not simply resize an image, but get a portion of an image and then put it into another image.

Comment: Then why didn't you mention that? Also, ImageMagick is pretty powerful. You should look through the documentation to see if it does what you want

Comment: `imagecopyresampled` does just that at the base. this is why I have not mentioned. I try to search in doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the response, I use node-gd. In previous search, i find an obsolete gd library for node.

This is the correct library : https://github.com/mikesmullin/node-gd

And to create empty imgage, use this function : `createTrueColor(width, height)`
To resample or cut image, use this : `copyResampled()`

This is similar to PHP functions, with same parameters. The wiki is available here : https://github.com/taggon/node-gd/wiki

And basic example :

```
var fs   = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var gd   = require('gd');
var source = './test.png';
var target = './test.thumb.png';

if (path.exists(target)) fs.unlink(target);

gd.openPng(
    source,
    function(png, path) {
        if(png) {
            var w = Math.floor(png.width/2), h = Math.floor(png.height/2);
            var target_png = gd.createTrueColor(w, h);

            png.copyResampled(target_png,0,0,0,0,w,h,png.width,png.height);
            target_png.savePng(target, 1, gd.noop);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. Have you noticed any performance differences between using GD with PHP and Node? Anything missing in the Node version? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, for me, gd nodeJS library is faster than PHP for the same task. But, i don't measure RAM and CPU usage.
I had to find some things by myself. But all in all (that I have tested), everything was present.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, if you install node-gd through NPM now, you'll be installing this maintained package: https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd